# Installing openCV: Bash cmake command not found

Tags: python, pi-4

I get an error return from typing the codes below:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
> -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
> -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
> -D ENABLE_NEON=ON \
> -D ENABLE_VFPV3=ON \
> -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
> -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
> -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
> -D CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS=-latomic \
> -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF ..
```

May I know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

@WJLee9559 you need to post your error otherwise there is a very slim chance that anyone will be able to solve it. Also, on Raspberry Pi it is much easier to install the python opencv package: `sudo pip3 install opencv-contrib-python`. Have you tried that first? Compiling from source on a Raspberry Pi is a long and painstaking process - I would not recommend it for something as huge as OpenCV.